# test coverage with try catch

Tags: apex, unit-test, try-catch

```java
public static void sendAlert(Id appId , String emailType, Boolean futureCall ) {
    sendAlert(appId, emailType);
}
    
public static void sendAlert(Id appId , String emailType ) {
    String smsMCloudFlag = System.Label.CastSendSMS;
    String emailFlag = System.Label.CastSendEmail;
    Map<String,String> appIdToEmailType = new Map<String,String>();
    appIdToEmailType.put(appId, emailType);
    try {
        // TODO : XLOB testing pls remove 
        // CastPkg_XLOBFactory.getXLOBService().syncAppointment(appId);
        if(emailType!='REMINDER' || smsMCloudFlag!='MarketingCloud'){
            sendSMS(appId, emailType);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        exceptionCount++;
        if(exceptionCount <= 1) 
            CastException.convertException(ex, 'CASTSms', 'sendSms');
        }
         
        try {
            if(emailFlag == 'Salesforce' || emailFlag =='Both'){
                sendEmail( appId, emailType, false );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            exceptionCount++;
            if(exceptionCount <= 1)
                CastException.convertException(ex, 'CASTEmail', 'sendEmail');
        }
        
        if((emailFlag == 'MarketingCloud' || emailFlag == 'Both' || smsMCloudFlag == 'MarketingCloud' || smsMCloudFlag == 'Both') && emailType!='REMINDER'){
            try{
               CastMarketingCloudService.upsertMarketingclouddata(appIdToEmailType); 
            }catch(exception exc){
                CastException.convertException(exc,'CastAlertService','upsertMarketingclouddata');
            }
        }
        if(emailFlag == 'MarketingCloud'){
            SendTemplateEmailConfirmation.sendXlobEmailInvite(appId , emailType);
        }     
    }
```

try with this method

```java
@IsTest static void testMethodException() { 
    Boolean exceptionCaught = false;
    Test.startTest();
    try { 
        // this should trigger null pointer exception 
        CastAlertService.sendSMS(123, 'email'); 
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        exceptionCaught = true; 
    } 

    Test.stopTest(); 
    System.assertEquals(true, exceptionCaught, 'exception was not caught'); 
}
```

Comment: try with this method    but not working @IsTest
    static void testMethodException() {
        Boolean exceptionCaught = false;
        
       Test.startTest();
        try {
            // this should trigger null pointer exception
            CastAlertService.sendSMS(123, 'email');
        } catch (Exception ex) {
               exceptionCaught = true;
            }
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertEquals(true, exceptionCaught, 'exception was not caught');
    }

Comment: Your catch block looks like it handles the exception without throwing a new one - hence the test method won't realize an exception was thrown. You need to change the testmethod to look for the artifacts created by the code-under-test's catch block

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.